# What kind of FEC is suitable for me?

Tags: error-correction

I'm sending over the air data block which is 144 bytes.
I can put additional 18 bytes of data for error correction.
The field for FEC looks very small and I can't find what I can use.
I have not requirements about BER, the number of bits to restore etc.
I need to fix as much as possible.
What FEC I can use for 162 bytes block where is 144 bytes data and 18 bytes FEC?

Comment: Why don't you tell us about the options and methods you have already considered so we don't reinvent the wheel. Have you done some research on this question yourself?

Comment: Does your system have horse power for a Reed-Solomon ECC code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many out there.

If you are a newbie, I suggest you to read Texas Instruments DN504 for a clear explanation and for a software implementation.

This  document gives an overview of the FEC implementation in the CC11XX, and CC25XX RF transceivers families.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra113a/swra113a.pdf?ts=1619516881539&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. What FEC I can use for 162 bytes block where is 144 bytes data and 18 bytes FEC?